# Serializing inside method field in Django REST framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

For example, I have two models: `Model1` and `Model2`. They are not related directly to each-other by any key-field on a model level. For both models I have serializers. I am searching the way to have `Model2` queryset in `Model1` serializer. For example:

```
GET /api/model1/01
```

According to `Model1` ID in request I can make query for `Model2` objects that I need to be sent in response. For now I have solution that I don't like: in `Model1` serializer I have method field that returns a list of objects. Is there any way to use `Model2` serializer in method field of Serializer1 or any other solution for my case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Solution-1: Using `Model2Serializer` in a `Model1`'s [`SerializerMethodField()`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)**

In this method, we define a `model2_data` `SerializerMethodField()` field in the `Model1Serializer`. There, we will first fetch all the `Model2` objects using the current `Model1` object. Then we initialize the `Model2Serializer` with `many=True` argument and pass all the obtained `Model2` instances. To return the serialized representation of `Model2` objects, we access the `.data` property.

```
class Model1Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    model2_data = serializers.SerializerMethodField() # define separate field

    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        fields = [.., 'model2_data']

    def get_model2_data(self, obj):
        # here write the logic to get the 'Model2' objects using 'obj'

        # initialize the 'Model2Serializer'
        model2_serializer = Model2Serializer(model2_objs, many=True)

        # return the serialized representation of 'Model2' objs
        return model2_serializer.data
```

**Solution-2: Overriding the `retrieve` method**

Another option is to override the `retrieve` method and add the `model2_data` to your response along with original response.

```
class MyView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):

    serializer_class = Model1Serializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)

        # get the original serialized data
        serialized_data = serializer.data

        # get the 'Model2' objects using 'serializer.instance'
        model2_serializer = Model2Serializer(model2_objs, many=True)
        model2_data = model2_serializer.data

        # add the serialized representation of `Model2` objs
        serialized_data['model2_data'] = model2_data

        return Response(serialized_data)
```

**PS**: I know these solutions are not clean. Had the two models been related, we could have approached the problem in a more cleaner way.

Comment: Thank you! I implemented first option and seems this is what I was looking for.